# How to boot a VirtualBox VM from a .img SD card image?

Tags: virtualbox, sd-card

I want to experiment with an hypervisor before setting up my server.
The hypervisor is SmartOS and recommends booting from a SD card, but Virtualbox does not allow me to set a virtual SD card, only virtual optical media or HDD are possible.

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Use Raw Partition Image in VirtualBox?](https://superuser.com/questions/645434/use-raw-partition-image-in-virtualbox)

```
$ hdiutil attach -imagekey diskimage-class=CRawDiskImage -nomount sd-card.img 
/dev/disk2              GUID_partition_scheme
/dev/disk2s1            Microsoft Basic Data
/dev/disk2s2            Linux Filesystem
$ VBoxManage internalcommands createrawvmdk -filename sd-card.vmdk -rawdisk /dev/disk2
```

While `sd-card.img` mounted at `/dev/disk2` you can attach `sd-card.vmdk` as any other hard disk to your VM.